# Nitrogen through systemd services doesn't work

Tags: linux, go, systemd, reddit, nitrogen

I am writing a tool ([zxcV32/OpenRWC](https://github.com/zxcV32/OpenRWC)) that fetches wallpapers from Reddit and sets them to the monitor(s) using [nitrogen](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/nitrogen).

To make it easy to install and run automatically, I have created a deb package and a systemd service.

When the service is started using

```
sudo systemctl start openrwc@$USER.service
```

`nitrogen` errors out with `exit status 1`. (No other error message). And yes, the exec installed by the deb package works fine when manually run from the terminal.

I have compared that the command run by the tool is precisely the same when run through the systemd service or terminal run.

Sample command

```
nitrogen --set-scaled /home/zxcv32/.config/OpenRWC/fz41kmzk1wj91.jpg --head=0
```

Service

```
[Unit]
Description=Reddit Wallpaper Changer for GNU/Linux
Requires=display-manager.service
After=display-manager.service
StartLimitIntervalSec=0

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/openrwc
Restart=always
RestartSec=5
User=%i

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

What may be wrong with the service? I want the service to be the user's choice, if they want to run it or not.

BTW I found this question that claims that nitrogen works through a service. (maybe there is a difference between running nitrogen directly through system service and through a go funciton)

System: Debian 11 5.10.0-17-amd64

Comment: The question:
How to run systemd service every hour but also everytime user logs in?
https://forum.endeavouros.com/t/how-to-run-systemd-service-every-hour-but-also-everytime-user-logs-in/27134

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because From the tag: systemd questions should be for *programming questions* using systemd or its libraries. Questions about *configuring the daemon* (including writing unit files) are better directed to Unix & Linux: https://unix.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue.

Systemd does not have access to certain environment variables.

`DISPLAY` environment variable needs to be set in the `openrwc@.service`.

```
[Service]
Environment="DISPLAY=:0"
```